# Make 100 random numbers and add them to table as primary key and catch error if duplicate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem. I am trying to add 100 random primary keys and catch error if the values is duplicate then add counter that counts the amount of errors and at the end prints out how many values are in ID and how many duplicate number errors there were.

I have done this so far but I am really new to T-SQL and I am not sure if this is even close.

Biggest problem is that I don't know how to get the value number from within the WITH and insert the given number to the table.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
DECLARE @I INT = 1
DECLARE @ERROR INT = 0
DECLARE @NUMBER INT

BEGIN TRY
    WITH CTE_Numbers(number) AS
    (
        SELECT 1 AS number
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT number + 1
        FROM CTE_Numbers
        WHERE number < 100 
    )
    SELECT TOP 1 number
    FROM CTE_Numbers
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

    BEGIN
        WHILE @I <= 100
        BEGIN   
            SET @NUMBER = (SELECT number FROM CTE_Numbers)
            INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES(@NUMBER)

            SET @I = @I + 1
        END
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @ERROR = @ERROR + 1
END CATCH

SELECT COUNT(ID) AS numbers, @ERROR AS errors
FROM @TABLE
```

Comment: so, where is your "random" part? And what is the current output if you execute your statement and on the cotrary what output did you expect? Last but not least: I would encapsulate the `INSERT INTO @TABLE...` in a try catch block and use this catch block to increase the number of errors...

Comment: The CTE_Numbers creates a value between 1-100 and that is the value i want to add to the table. number is the random generated number

Comment: `with ... select top 1 @Number = Number from CTE_Numbers order by NewId() option ( MaxRecursion 0 )`? That gets you one value, which is about as many as you can fit in `@Number`. Curious that you don't handle errors _inside_ the loop, you just abandon the whole thing on the first error of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully get what you're doing but this should get you started. @rows is how many rows you want, @high is the highest ID (between 1 and @high).

```
--==== Parameters
DECLARE 
  @rows INT = 10, -- Return this many rows
  @high INT = 20;  -- Number = 1 to @high

--==== Prep
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t;

--==== Create and Populate #t with random numbers 
WITH 
e1(x) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS x(x)),
t(N)  AS (SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%@high)+1 FROM e1 a, e1 b, e1 c, e1 d) -- up to 10K
SELECT TOP(@rows) t.N INTO #t FROM t;

--==== Counts
SELECT
  UniqueIds  = SUM(IIF(f.T=1, 1, 0)),
  Duplicates = SUM(IIF(f.T=1, 0, 1))
FROM
(
  SELECT   t.N, COUNT(*)
  FROM     #t AS t
  GROUP BY t.N
) AS f(N,T);

--==== Santiy Check
SELECT   t.N, ttl = COUNT(*)
FROM     #t AS t
GROUP BY t.N
```

**Returns: (random)**

```
UniqueIds   Duplicates
----------- -----------
2           4

N           ttl
----------- -----------
2           2
5           1
6           2
8           2
12          2
14          1
```